# how to calculate accuracy from decision trees?

Tags: decision-tree

[image]

Hi, I am taking a course on Coursera and came into this question. My answer is 1-(4048+3456)/8124=0.076. However, the answer is 0.067. Anybody can help me to solve this? Thank you!!

Comment: What course is this?

Comment: Coursera applied machine learning in python -- not sure how asking the question here (or taking complete answer) jibes with the honor code

Comment: I found this not well explained in one of the UoW courses, so I am glad you posted.

Answer (score 22):

Accuracy: The number of correct predictions made divided by the total number of predictions made.

We're going to predict the majority class associated with a particular node as True. i.e. use the larger value attribute from each node.

So the accuracy for:

- Depth 1: (3796 + 3408) / 8124
- Depth 2: (3760 + 512 + 3408 + 72) / 8124

> Depth_2 - Depth_1 = 0.06745

Answer (score 13):

First We will draw confusion metrics for both cases and then find accuracy.

Confusion metrics:

[image]

Accuracy= (TP + TN) / (Total number of observation)

Accuracy calculation:

```
Depth 1: (3796 + 3408) / 8124

Depth 2: (3760 + 512 + 3408 + 72) / 8124

Depth_2 - Depth_1 = 0.06745
```

Answer (score 0):

Though answer is correct but the confusion matrix looks not correct.
This should be the confusion matrix( for depth-2).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w4Dq.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).